# I can't see .router-link-active or .router-link-exact-active on my route after I redirect route by using beforeEnter

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I redirect component by using beforeEnter, and I don't see .router-link-active or .router-link-exact-active therefore css is not working. Please help me!

```
{
  path: 'parent',
  component: parent,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      name: 'ChildOne',
      component: 'ChildOne'
    },
    {
      path: 'two',
      name: 'ChildTwo',
      component: ChildTwo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        if (isAuth) {
          next({ name: 'ChildOne'})
        } else {
          next()
        }
      }
    }
 ]
}
```

so.. it will redirect to ChildOne and ChildOne do not have .router-link-active or .router-link-exact-active.

Comment: Without a sample of your code it's extremely unlikely that we can help you.

Comment: I just added some example..please let me if it doesn't make sense. Thank you!

Comment: are you aware, that the classes will only be added to the occurences of `<router-link>` that point to the currently active route, and not on the Component you're showing? Please specify your problem further, I'm using redirects the same way and I have no trouble seeing the classes added on my navigation links

Comment: you mean when I am on ChildOne page, I would see class="router-link-active"?

Comment: I can't see any class when I am on ChildOne page. I don't understand.. because <router-link> should have both .router-link-active or .router-link-exact-active by default.. Do you know any possible cases that <router-link> don't have these classes?

Comment: Also.. I tried, I removed the beforeEnter so that it can direct ChildTwo. I was able to see those classes..

Comment: Can you post the code where you use `router-link`? because I tested it in any way possible and it always shows the classes as expected.